# GroupedObservable: children don't display using *ngFor and async pipe

Tags: html, angular, rxjs, frontend, observable

I have a collection of objects that I am grouping by a *type* property. I am using the RxJs GroupedObservable operator in combination with the Angular **ngFor* directive and *async* pipe to achieve this.

For some reason Angular is able to render the text of the group key property, but it's not rendering any HTML for the items in the grouped collection.

**Object interface:**

```
export interface Accessorial {
  code: string;
  description: string;
  type: string;
  isSelected: boolean;
}
```

**Component accessor:**

```
this.groupedAccessorials = accessorialsObservable
      .mergeMap((collection) => {
        return collection;
      })
      .groupBy(item => item.type,
               item => item)
      .toArray();
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngIf="groupedAccessorials | async">
     <div *ngFor="let group of groupedAccessorials| async">
        <h3>{{group.key}}</h3>
          <div *ngFor="let accessorial of group | async">
            <span>------------------------------------------</span><br/>
            {{accessorial.code}}<br/>
            {{accessorial.description}}<br/>
            {{accessorial.type}}<br/>
            <span>------------------------------------------</span><br/><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

**Rendered HTML:**

[image: ngFor Markup]

***EDIT***:

*output of* `{{_groupedAccessorials | json}}` per @Dimitry-Grinko's request:

```
{
    "_isScalar" : false,
    "key" : "Origin",
    "groupSubject" : {
        "_isScalar" : false,
        "observers" : [],
        "closed" : false,
        "isStopped" : true,
        "hasError" : false,
        "thrownError" : null
    },
    "refCountSubscription" : {
        "closed" : true,
        "_parent" : null,
        "_parents" : null,
        "_subscriptions" : null,
        "syncErrorValue" : null,
        "syncErrorThrown" : false,
        "syncErrorThrowable" : false,
        "isStopped" : true,
        "destination" : {
            "closed" : true,
            "_parent" : null,
            "_parents" : null,
            "_subscriptions" : null,
            "syncErrorValue" : null,
            "syncErrorThrown" : false,
            "syncErrorThrowable" : false,
            "isStopped" : true,
            "destination" : {
                "closed" : true,
                "_parent" : null,
                "_parents" : null,
                "_subscriptions" : null,
                "syncErrorValue" : null,
                "syncErrorThrown" : false,
                "syncErrorThrowable" : false,
                "isStopped" : true,
                "destination" : {
                    "closed" : true
                },
                "_parentSubscriber" : null,
                "_context" : null
            }
        },
        "groups" : {
            "values" : {}
        },
        "attemptedToUnsubscribe" : true,
        "count" : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `toArray()` operator?

Comment: @Brandon if I do that, then I get an exception from the *ngFor directive saying that it's an [object Object] and not an iterable. It's definitely iterating through the different groups, because the "key" is being printed out (see the screenshot at the bottom)

Comment: Try to remove `async` from `<div *ngFor="let accessorial of group | async">`

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten - thanks, but following your suggestion the subscription is created multiple times outputting this error indefinitely: `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: @Rob sorry, but I guess I disagree with the community here. The generated HTML by Angular is not something likely to be searched by those trying to help. Chrome's dev tools lays it out in a more readable format than SO's markup can. Why even allow image uploads if they're never to be used?

Comment: Images are allowed NOT for posting code.

Comment: @Rob you didn't even address anything I said. By the way, I don't see why you'd vote to close this question as off-topic. Have yourself a good day...